# How to connect to remote mysql database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database using node. It is working perfectly fine when connecting with localhost.

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100,
    host     : 'http://<ip-address here>/phpmyadmin',
    user     : '*********',
    password : '*********',
    database : '*********'
});

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // Use the connection
  connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM table', function(err, rows) {
  // And done with the connection.
  connection.release();

  // Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
   });
});
```

The above code is not working.
I haven't found any answer on Google as well as here.

Answer (score 0):

Host is only contains IP address, try to remove phpmyadmin.